# Resolving error when using a web service as Jar in another web service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, jar, war

I am developing a Web Service's for my company, I have a fully working Web Service that connects to database and I need to add it as a Jar into another fully functional Web Service.
I have included the exec Jar of first Web Service in pom of second Web Service. When I run the second Web Service through my IDE(STS) it works fine, but when I create a War file of my second Web Service and try to run the War file through Apache Tomcat it raises following error.

> 03-Dec-2018 12:58:16.190 SEVERE [http-nio-8090-exec-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log FAIL - Application at
>   context path /gd-erp-1.0.0 could not be started 
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/gd-erp-1.0.0]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1294)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:659)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:210)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:604)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1152)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'aisleController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'applicationService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'applicationService': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'userAssignmentServce'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userAssignmentsService': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'entityManager'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:
>   No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager'
>   available: expected single matching bean but found 3:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#2
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5352)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     ... 32 more

My requirement is to have a fully working WebService that connects to DB and work in second WebService like its part of this WebService.

Update: added pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>spring-web-service</name>
    <description>Web Service using Spring boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup
 parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- DevTools dependency - it makes server restart
 automatically(in 1-2           secs) within less time than manual restart
 takes(ie 10-20 sec). -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>            groupId>org.projectlombok
        </groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Model mapper library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Swagger dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java
 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Log4j 2 Dependencies start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <!--
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-jcl
 -->
    <!-- <dependency><groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId><version>2.5</version>$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ </dependency> -->
    <!--
 Log4j 2 Dependencies end -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependencies for GreyDelta Utils -->
    <!--
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <!--
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons.io/commonsIO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
        <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <!--
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core
 -->
    <!-- <dependency><groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId><artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId><version>2.11.0</version>$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ </dependency> -->
    <!--
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
    <!-- <dependency><groupId>commons-logging</groupId><artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId><version>1.2</version></dependency> -->
</dependencies>
<!--    <build><plugins><plugin><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId></plugin></plugins></build>  -->
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-web-service</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: `No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#1,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#2 at `

Comment: Paste your `pom.xml` too.

Comment: I have added the pom file